# Take throws exception if not exist in efcore

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I want to get maximum amount of 10 objects from a table but it throws exception if there not 10 objects in db.
how can I prevent crashing and not to take more than 10 objects from database.

```
e.Include(x => x.GroupChatMessage).TakeLast(10);
```

Comment: Which `OrderBy` do you have? Invert `OrderBy` and use `Take(10)`.

Comment: what order by?
I dont want to order. I just want to take @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: SQL Server do not guarantee order of records. Without `OrderBy`, `Take` is Undefined behavior.